# How to remove sp.RequestExecutors.js console.logs?

Tags: jsom, requestexecutor

I have sea of logs from this file in console. Little bit annoying to find my own console.logs in it, and also console lags a bit.
How can I disable it? Maybe in SharePoint online settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable it with configuration

Things you can do:

- Use filter 'myapp.js' in console to only show log statements coming from **myapp.js**
- (Chrome) enhance your logging to display colors
  `console.log('%c MyApp:' , 'background:green;color:white' , mydata );`
- (coding, difficult) Monkey Patch sp.RequestExecutors.js, overwrite/disable logging code
- ...

Comment: Monkey patching sp.RequestExecutor.js might not be enough because sometimes the code runs partially in an iframe where security settings prevent tinkering with the code